# Return unique values of an array without using `uniq`

Tags: arrays, ruby

For a challenge, I'm trying to return the unique values of an array without using `uniq`. This is what I have so far, which doesn't work:

```
def unique
   unique_arr = []
   input_arr.each do |word|
     if word != unique_arr.last
       unique_arr.push word
     end
   end
   puts unique_arr
end
input = gets.chomp
input_arr = input.split.sort
input_arr.unique
```

My reasoning here was that if I sorted the array first before I iterated through it with `each`, I could `push` it to `unique_arr` without repetition being a possibility considering if it's a duplicate, the last value pushed would match it.

Am I tackling this the wrong way?

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? Personal exercise?

Comment: Yeah I'm only a beginner. I hadn't even heard of `uniq` until the challenge told me not to use it.

Comment: Your question was misleading. If it is meant to work only on a sorted array, then you should have written so, and not just implying that (subtlely) in the code. And you should note that that is different from what `uniq` does.

Comment: Or add the sort to the example code.

Comment: If you are going to apply `split` on `input`, what is the point of doing `chomp`?

Comment: Please post these kind of questions to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is the enter input not recorded when using `split`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are making at least two mistakes.

1. If you want to call it as `input_arr.unique` with `input_arr` being an array, then you have to define the method on `Array`. You have `input_arr` within your method body, which comes from nowhere.
2. `puts` in the last line of your code outputs to the terminal, but makes the method return `nil`, which makes it behave differently from `uniq`.

It can be fixed as:

```
class Array
  def unique
    unique_arr = []
    each do |word|
      unique_arr.push(word) unless unique_arr.last == word
    end
    unique_arr
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

A unique array? That sounds like a [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) to me:

```
require 'set'

Set.new([1,2,3,2,3,4]).to_a
#=> [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: yea, Set is a perfect solution!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a concise way to do it that doesn't explicitly use functionality from another class but probably otherwise misses the point of the challenge:

```
class Array
  def unique
    group_by(&:itself).keys
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I try this three options. Just for challenge

```
class Array
  def unique
    self.each_with_object({}) { |k, h| h[k] = k }.keys
  end

  def unique2
    self.each_with_object([]) { |k, a| a << k unless a.include?(k) }
  end

  def unique3
    arr = []
    self.map { |k| arr << k unless arr.include?(k) }
    arr
  end
end
```

Comment: In `unique`, what is the point of making the hash value  (not the key) `k`? Won't a value like `true` suffice and be simpler?

Comment: In `unique3`, why are you explicitly writing `self`? What is the point of using `map`?

Comment: @sawa In `unique` I just try to show more ways to do this "challenge", ofc you are right with the `true` insted of `k`. In `unique3` i use `map` bcs of more speed and like "new" way have uniq values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way to do this:

```
uniques = a.each.with_object([]) {|el, arr| arr << el if not arr.include?(el)}
```

Answer (score -1):

That's so easy if you see it this way:

```
a = [1,1,2,3,4]
h = Hash.new
a.each{|q| h[q] = q}
h.values
```

and this will return:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```